# How can I give TTL and versions to hbase table through phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to use hbase table through phoenix tool. I want to manipulate the TTL time and version of the table created through phoenix.
I tried to change it through hbase-site.xml but it wont.
Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "manipulate"? Did you see that:

Example: (see TTL attribute)

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.my_table ( id BIGINT not null primary key, date DATE not null)
CREATE TABLE my_table ( id INTEGER not null primary key desc, date DATE not null,
    m.db_utilization DECIMAL, i.db_utilization)
    m.DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING='DIFF'
CREATE TABLE stats.prod_metrics ( host char(50) not null, created_date date not null,
    txn_count bigint CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (host, created_date) )
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "my_case_sensitive_table"
    ( "id" char(10) not null primary key, "value" integer)
    DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING='NONE',VERSIONS=5,MAX_FILESIZE=2000000 split on (?, ?, ?)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.my_table (
    org_id CHAR(15), entity_id CHAR(15), payload binary(1000),
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (org_id, entity_id) )
    TTL=86400
```